# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in macos

Tags: c, gcc

today when I using this command to compile synctex_parser.c file(https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex) in mac with Intel Chip, shows error like this:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared synctex_parser.c -o synctex_parser.so                                                                       ‹ruby-2.7.2›

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__synctex_base_name", referenced from:
      __synctex_scanner_get_tag in synctex_parser-acaaec.o
  "__synctex_copy_with_quoting_last_path_component", referenced from:
      ___synctex_open_v2 in synctex_parser-acaaec.o
```

using this same code and command in linux works fine, why the mac could not compile this c file? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the clang version:

```
$ gcc --version                                                                                                                 ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Presumably you need to compile all the .c files into one library.

Comment: i just need to invoke the synctex_parser.c function, I need to compile the whole project? there is no manual or document and makefile to do this.

Comment: The function `_synctex_base_name` that's used in `synctex_parser.c` comes from `synctex_parser_utils.c`, so at least that file needs to be compiled too. By default I'd just compile all provided files and not overthink it.

Comment: Yes you need to compile the whole project. On Linux too. Try running it on Linux without compiling the whole project, does it run?

Comment: on linux it works with just compile the synxtex_parser.c file. I am trying to compile the whole project, there is no document and I am not fimiliar with C project. The readme told compile with xcode, and still facing issue with this tool, I just want to invoke the c function from rust, it look like so hard.